# implode() invalid arguments

Tags: php, implode

When I try to run this code:

```
$arraytest = implode(", ", $array['playerList']); print $arraytest;
```

I'm getting this error:

> Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in /home/crafter/public_html/index.php

It's supposed to fetch info about my minecraft server.

I did var_dump() on it and it responded NULL. I automatically assumed it was an array since I got this script from the bukkit forums...

Comment: Well, what's `$array['playerList']`?

Comment: Do `var_dump($array);` and I'm sure you'll find your answer.

Comment: please `var_dump($array['playerList']);` and post here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$array['playerList']` must be an array, it probably isn't.

Answer (score 4):

`$array['playerList']` probably isn't an array. You can check with:
`echo gettype($array['playerList']);`